# What architecture for a SIEM based on an ELK cluster?

Tags: siem

First thoughts to build a SIEM based on ELK, inside a multi-locations company :

- All assets send their log to Logstash locally (for each location)
- ElasticSearch stores the logs locally after Logstash parsing
- ElasticSearch filters the logs usefull for the SIEM (security logs) and send them to a local output logstash
- This one sends these security logs to a centrilized ELK stack (common to the whole company), under a VPN
- Correlation rules are parsed on the centrilized ELK to throw up security alarms

Other alternatives may be:

- No centrilized ElasticSearch since ELK enables searching on a cluster. Advantage : less bandwidth requirements since the security logs stay local. Drawback : possibly latency
- Use of message queues to provide better robustness, especially for small locations with the minimal number of ELK nodes

In the context of a SIEM and taking into account inherent security, what would be the best architecture and elements in our case ?

Comment: Why do you want to sent logs from Logstash to Elasticsearch and then back to another instance of Logstash? The purpose of Logstash is parsing and filtering.

Comment: From discussions with my system administrators, Logstash is used also to output data from Elastic. Besides, we want to store locally all logs, and send to the centrilized ELK only the ones usefull for the SIEM (probably a few percents of them) in order to save bandwidth

Comment: I'm not seeing a security question here. I'm not sure how being for a SIEM materially affects the question

Comment: This comes in the "security tools" topic of the help center, this is not a general ELK questionning

Answer (score 1):

From a security perspective, I would recommend shipping and saving all the logs off site. You can use Filebeat/winlogbeat (which supports compression) to send to a remote Logstash. Logstash is very, very fast and you shouldn't worry about pounding it with logs. Once there, run Elasticsearch to query on the data you want to. This would be the best set up for latency and from a security aspect as filebeat/winlogbeat supports mutual authentication with Logstash. It is recommended that you **do** have a centralized Elasticsearch Cluster because that really is the purpose of using a flexible stack such as ELK. Once the data is sitting in your cluster, you can write queries and and return results or have external services/tools do so. I would be careful though because Elasticsearch does not implement any security features such as access control.